# Get unicode character with curl in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I tried to get URL with curl. Return value contain unicode character. curl convert to \u for unicode character. How to get unicode character with curl ?

This is my code

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.ornagai.com/index.php/api/word/q/test/format/json");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$return=curl_exec($ch);
echo $return;
?>
```

Return json is following

```
[{"word":"test","state":"n","def":"\u1005\u102c\u1031\u1019\u1038\u1015\u1032\u103c\u104b \u1005\u1005\u1039\u1031\u1006\u1038\u103b\u1001\u1004\u1039\u1038\u104b \u1005\u1005\u1039\u1031\u1006\u1038\u1019\u1088\u104b \u1031\u1006\u1038\u1005\u1005\u1039\u103b\u1001\u1004\u1039\u1038\u104b \u1005\u1019\u1039\u1038\u101e\u1015\u1039\u103b\u1001\u1004\u1039\u1038\u104b"},{"word":"test","state":"v","def":"\u1005\u1005\u1039\r"},{"word":"test case","state":"n","def":"\u1031\u1014\u102c\u1004\u1039\u1039\u103b\u1016\u1010\u1039\u1011\u1036\u102f\u1038\u103b\u1016\u1005\u1039\u1019\u100a\u1039\u1037\u1005\u1036\u1014\u1019\u1030\u1014\u102c\u103b\u1015\u1021\u1019\u1088\u104b"},{"word":"test drive","state":"n","def":"\u1005\u1019\u1039\u1038\u101e\u1015\u1039\u1031\u1019\u102c\u1004\u1039\u1038\u108f\u103d\u1004\u1039\u103b\u1001\u1004\u1039\u1038\u104b \u1005\u1019\u1039\u1038\u101e\u1015\u1039\u1031\u1019\u102c\u1004\u1039\u1038\u101e\u100a\u1039\u104b"},{"word":"test match","state":"n","def":"\u1001\u101b\u1005\u1039\u1000\u1000\u1039\u104a\u101b\u1010\u1039\u1062\u1018\u102e\u108f\u103d\u1005\u1039\u108f\u102d\u102f\u1004\u1039\u1004\u1036\u1021\u101e\u1004\u1039\u1038\u1019\u103a\u102c\u1038\u104f\u101c\u1000\u1039\u101b\u100a\u1039\u1005\u1019\u1039\u1038\u1015\u1032\u103c\u104b"},{"word":"test pilot","state":"n","def":"\u1031\u101c\u101a\u102c\u1009\u1039\u1015\u1036\u102f\u1005\u1036\u101e\u1005\u1039\u1000\u102d\u102f\u1005\u1019\u1039\u1038\u101e\u1015\u1039\u1031\u1019\u102c\u1004\u1039\u1038\u108f\u103d\u1004\u1039\u101e\u100a\u1039\u1037\u1031\u101c\u101a\u102c\u1009\u1039\u1019\u1089\u1038\u104b"},{"word":"test the waters","state":"idm","def":"\u1031\u101e\u103c\u1038\u1010\u102d\u102f\u1038\u1005\u1019\u1039\u1038\u101e\u100a\u1039\u104b"},{"word":"test-tube","state":"n","def":"\u1005\u1019\u1039\u1038\u101e\u1015\u1039\u1016\u1014\u1039\u103b\u1015\u103c\u1014\u1039\u104b \u1013\u102c\u1010\u1039\u1001\u1032\u103c\u1001\u1014\u1039\u1038\u1016\u1014\u1039\u103b\u1015\u103c\u1014\u1039\u104b"},{"word":"test-tube baby","state":"n","def":"\u1016\u1014\u1039\u103b\u1015\u103c\u1014\u1039\u101e\u1031\u108f\u1076\u101e\u102c\u1038\u104b"},{"word":"testable","state":"adj","def":"\u1005\u1019\u1039\u1038\u101e\u1015\u1039\u1005\u1005\u1039\u1031\u1006\u1038\u1001\u1036\u108f\u102d\u102f\u1004\u1039\u1031\u101e\u102c\u104b"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

curl will get you whatever the remote server sends : it will not interpret anything, or do any modification on the data it gets.

If you have `\uxxxx` characters in what curl returns, it's because those are returned by the remote server.

And having `\uxxxx` characters in JSON data should not be a problem : it's the way unicode characters should be encoded, when using JSON -- see the definition of strings, on http://json.org/

Those should be interpreted correctly by Javascript, when using that JSON data.

Comment: I call from friefox is return character. But not work in curl. You mean, it's a problem from remote server send.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem at all, in fact : that's the way unicode characters are represented, with JSON. ;;; maybe Firefox is interpreting those codes, to display you the corresponding characters ?

Comment: I got it. It's problem from PHP when using json_encode. It's ok when I use json_decode it.

Comment: Glad to hear that you found out what was causing your problem ;-)